# snakemake; remote module from private github repos; no access?

Tags: github, module, snakemake

In snakemake I'm trying to use modules from private github repos', but am getting "Failed to open source file"/"HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: " when the repos is private but not when it is public. I understood from docs that private repos' should be possible. I've used gh CLI to authenticate but am actually not sure this is necessary or sufficient.
Can anybody confirm that accessing private repos' from snakemake should be possible? Can anybody tell me whether/what authentication is required?

Thanks! Ludo

Comment: From [the code](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/23d40d99614a88fd3c596d05e6915509ae43d4ce/snakemake/sourcecache.py#L216), I almost expect they aren't even cloning, just straight trying to pull the file as a URL. I'd file an issue on the repo.

Comment: I've filed a feature request; https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1301

Comment: I've opened a PR to implement this: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1761